# Detemining if a webapp is stateless

Tags: angularjs, node.js, hapi.js, stateless

I've recently taken over the development of an in-house webapp following the departure of the previous dev.

One of the things on the to-do list is to implement multiple processes on the Server, which digging around seems to be reasonably easily implemented using PM2.

*However* one of the requirements of PM2 is that the application should be stateless and I'm struggling to fully understand what I need to chase down.

The basic architecture is REST with Node/Hapi on the backend with Angular on the frontend.

I'm fairly certain that the backend is written so that we pass the information that we need from the front end and only act on what is passed.

How far do we need to go on the front end. Do we need to eliminate storing client-side information in $scope? Should I care whether there is anything in Local Storage or Session Storage in Chrome Dev Tools?

Answer (score 2):

Stateless in this context means that the Hapi server should not maintain any state between api requests.  In a typical setup you might have database, api server and client (web browser).  When a client makes a request to your api, if all it does is perform some logic, carry out a transaction on the database, then return the result to the client then you can say the api server is 'stateless'.

If, on the other hand, the Hapi server keeps the result of that transaction in memory (caching) in case any future request asks for it, you have a 'stateful' server which could deliver out of date information if another instance updates the database in the meantime.

The two main areas to focus on would be session data and websockets.  Session data needs to be store out-of-process, i.e. in the database or an in-memory store such as Redis.  Websockets need to have something called 'sticky session' enabled for them to work with clusters.  Not had to do that myself, but there is a node module [`sticky-session`](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) that performs most of the work.

Comment: That's what I thought, and I'm pretty sure that the API is stateless, but knowing where to focus makes the task manageable

Answer (score 1):

PM2 requires an app to be stateless to guarantee that any request is processed the same way (e.g. has the same response and side-effects) regardless what worker (server instance) it is processed on.

Thus, you should not care about front end app. Statelessness requirement is just not applied to it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to clarify this with your PM. 
Depending on definition no website is really stateless (caches). 
Then again as soon as you have any session or auth you have got state.

Forget about that $scope/LocalStorage thing as long as you dont want to remove most useful features. Mooost likely this is a BS requirement if not specified further.

Comment: Small team. No PM to consult. Stateless requirement comes from PM2 for the reasons mentioned by Sergey. Just trying to wrap my head around what aspects of the design I need to ensure are stateless so I don't go chasing geese

Comment: Well thats a different story and a valid requirement. I misunderstood PM2 as Project Manager 2 (like you are talking about different people). Sorry for that. 

If you are using a sql database you could start looking if you should wrap some operations into transactions.